An interesting bijective function on $\Bbb Z_{26}$
In order to get the last letter of any italian tax code it is used the following bijective function on $\Bbb Z_{26}$.
$f:\Bbb Z_{26}\to\Bbb Z_{26}$ defined as follows :
$f(0)\!=\!1,\,f(1)\!=\!0,\,f(2)\!=\!5,\,f(3)\!=\!7,\,f(4)\!=\!9,\,f(5)\!=\!13,$
$f(6)\!=\!15\,,\;f(7)\!=\!17\,,\;f(8)\!=\!19\,,\;f(9)\!=\!21\,,\;f(10)\!=\!2\,,$
$f(11)\!=\!4\,,\,f(12)\!=\!18\,,\,f(13)\!=\!20\,,\,f(14)\!=\!11\,,\,f(15)\!=\!3\,,$
$f(16)\!=\!6\,,\,f(17)\!=\!8\,,\,f(18)\!=\!12\,,\,f(19)\!=\!14\,,\,f(20)\!=\!16\,,$
$f(21)\!=\!10,\,f(22)\!=\!22,\,f(23)\!=\!25,\,f(24)\!=\!24,\,f(25)\!=\!23.$
I am looking for a closed formula in order to get the value $f(x)$ for any $x\in\Bbb Z_{26}\,.$
My attempts:
I have tried to get the values of the coefficients $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z\,$ such that $\;f(x)=ax+b\;$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb Z_{26}\,$
but there do not exist such values of $a$ and $b$.
Indeed from $\;f(0)=1\;,\;f(1)=0\;,\;f(2)=5\;,$
it follows that
$\begin{cases}b=1+26\lambda\\[3pt]a+b=26\mu\\[3pt]2a+b=5+26\sigma\end{cases}\quad$ where $\;\lambda,\mu,\sigma\in\Bbb Z$
but it is impossible.
So I have tried to get the values of the coefficients $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb Z\,$ such that
$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\;$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb Z_{26}\,$
but there do not exist such values of $a,b$ and $c$.
Of course there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree less or equal to $25$ called polynomial interpolation such that
$f(x)=P(x)\;$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb Z_{26}\,$
but if the degree of $P(x)$ is not ”small” (for example $15$ or greater than it), it is not useful to get that polynomial $P(x)$ because it would contain a lot of coefficients and so it would be almost the same thing as writing explicitly the $26$ values of the function $f(x)$.
Is it possible to get a closed form such as
$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\;$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb Z_{26}\,$
where $\,n\,$ is ”small” (for example less than $10$) ?
Does there exist a better and short closed form for the function $f(x)$ which involves other operations (not just polynomials) ?
Edit:
Thanks to the comments I have read, I have understood that there does not exist any polynomial $P(x)$ such that $f(x)=P(x)\;$ on $\;\Bbb Z_{26}\;$ since $\;\Bbb Z_{26}\;$ is not a field.
But could you help me to find a closed form for the function $f(x)$ by using other expressions which are not polynomials ?

+1  for beginning with "In order to get the last letter of any Italian tax code".

Is there any reason to imagine that there's a more sensible function underlying this than the simple look up table?

As an element of $S_{23}$ it has cycle structure $(22)(24)(0,1)(12,18)(23,25)(2,5,13,20,16,6,15,3,7,17,8,19,14,11,4,9,21,20)$, for whatever that's worth.

@lulu, the last letter of any italian tax code is used as a control character, so I do not think that the values of the function $f(x)$ are completely random. They have been generated in some way by using some rule, so I think there exists a closed and short form for the function $f(x)$.

you can't write f as a polynomial in this way (it would have to preserve congruences mod 2, and it doesn't).  The thing about polynomial interpolation isn't right e.g. $g:\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ given by $g(0)=1, g(1)=0, g(2)=2, g(3)=3$ is a permutation that is not an integer polynomial of degree 4 (you'd need $g(z)=1+az+bz^2+cz^3$ so that $g(0)=1$, but then $g(2)=2$ is $2a=1$ which is impossible mod 4)

Yeah, I don't know.  US Social Security numbers have coded meanings as well, but they depend on timing and odd accidents of geography and political priorities.

Polynomial interpolation only works in fields, and unfortunately 26 does not a field make.

here is Wikipedia on the subject (I didn't study it carefully).

@lulu, I know what Wikipedia says, but I would like to get a closed form for the function which gives the values of the table concerning the “odd characters”.

@lulu, the last number you wrote in the cycle structure should not be $20$ but $10$. Am I wrong ?

I would imagine the table is made with certain properties in mind rather than by a function. For example, it might be desirable that swapping neighbouring digits by mistake is guaranteed to make the check digit false. And so on. It would be interesting to reverse engineer what sort of nice properties may come from using this table

See permutation polynomials. $\ \ $

@trebor But one could find a polynomial with rational coefficients which has the desired behavior for $1\leq x\leq 26$.

You should explain in a bit more detail as to how this relates to the Italian tax code, otherwise this reads like trying to fit a function to a bunch of random points on a very specific type of ring.

@Mike, read this and look at the “odd characters” table.

Yes, you are correct.  The last cycle ends in $10$.  My guess, again, is that there is no simple function.  The thing is design to facilitate a check sum, so they will be careful to register transposition errors (the most common typing error).  That will dictate some properties of the choice.   Then, my guess is, they played around till they found a string that worked well enough.

@lulu, if you look at the “odd characters” table, the digits $0!-!9$ have the same values as the first ten letters $A!-!J$ and it is not a pure coincidence. So I think there exists some rule which could be written through a closed formula.

@BillDubuque, please, could you write an answer by using the permutation polynomials properties you have found ?
